# Add Label that move along my custom Progress-Bar

Tags: wpf, styles, progress-bar

I have this `GridViewColumn.CellTemplate`:

```
<GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
              <Grid Margin="-6,0,0,0">
                    <ProgressBar Name="progressBarColumn"
                                 Minimum="0"
                                 Maximum="100"
                                 Value="{Binding Progress, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                 Style="{StaticResource CustomProgressBar4}"
                                 Width="350"
                                 Margin="0,0,0,0"/>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="fileNameTextBlock"
                               Text="{Binding File}"
                               VerticalAlignment="Center"
                               Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
              </Grid>
          </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
```

Inside my `Progress-Bar` instead of show the `Percentage` i change it to show my Binding File:

```
Text="{Binding File}"
```

And my `Style`:

```
<Style x:Key="CustomProgressBar4" TargetType="ProgressBar">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ProgressBar" >
                    <Grid x:Name="Root">
                        <Border Name="PART_Track" 
                                CornerRadius="5" 
                                Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding Background}"                                
                                BorderThickness="1"/>
                        <Border Name="PART_Indicator" 
                                CornerRadius="5" 
                                Background="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" 
                                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" 
                                BorderThickness="1" 
                                HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

So my Progress-Bar is filled according my `Progress` value (binding) and i want to add simple `Label\TextBlock` that will locate on the right side of my `Progress-Bar` and will show my `Progress` value.

Any suggestions how to do that ?

Comment: add `<TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Value}" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>` inside Grid in Template?

Comment: This also should be move according the value

Comment: "simple Label\TextBlock that will locate on the right side" is a contradiction with "should be move according the value"

Comment: Ok i add this inside my style but i cannot see it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just simply define two Grid columns then add a TextBlock to the second column

```
  <Style TargetType="ProgressBar">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ProgressBar">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid x:Name="Root" Grid.Column="0">
                            <Border Name="PART_Track"
                                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                    BorderThickness="1"
                                    CornerRadius="5" />
                            <Border Name="PART_Indicator"
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                    Background="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                                    BorderThickness="1"
                                    CornerRadius="5" />
                        </Grid>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1"
                                   HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                   Text="{Binding Path=Value,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```